# How i can build container by docker-compose.yml environment variable?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

How i can build container by docker-compose.yml environment variable?

For example, I try:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: 'production'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM isterjakov/nginx-passenger
# ...
#                           ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
RUN echo "export RAILS_ENV='$RAILS_ENV'" >> /home/docker/.profile
# ...
```

But the variable still empty :( 
How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it as a build argument e.g:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        RAILS_ENV: 'production'
```

Personally however, I would only use Compose for running applications and do the build step separately.